# Error in Elixir : returned a bad value: :ok

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have some problem while working on Elixir.
This is my `mix.exs`...

```
defmodule FlockTest.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :flock_test,
     version: "0.1.0",
     elixir: "~> 1.4",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps()]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application
  #
  # Type "mix help compile.app" for more information
  def application do
    # Specify extra applications you'll use from Erlang/Elixir
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger],
      mod: {FlockTest, []}
    ]
  end
...
...
```

and this is code for `FlockTest`.

```
defmodule FlockTest do
  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for FlockTest.
  """

  def start(_type, _args) do
    IO.puts "Start Flock"
  end
end
```

I run this code with `mix run --no-halt` but this caused error like this.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 12-Nov-2017::17:47:39 ===
    application: logger
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
** (Mix) Could not start application flock_test: FlockTest.start(:normal,     
[]) returned a bad value: :ok
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your application's `start/2` function should start and return the top level process of the application, usually a supervisor instance. Right now you return the value returned by `IO.puts`, which is `:ok` on success. The valid return values are `{:ok, pid} | {:ok, pid, state} | {:error, reason :: term}` as documented [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#c:start/2). For an example of this, you can create a new application using `mix new foo --sup` and check out `lib/foo/application.ex`. Here's how its `start/2` looks like:

```
def start(_type, _args) do
  # List all child processes to be supervised
  children = [
    # Starts a worker by calling: A.Worker.start_link(arg)
    # {A.Worker, arg},
  ]

  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
  # for other strategies and supported options
  opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: A.Supervisor]
  Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
end
```